# How to use dag_run.conf for typed arguments

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG that create a Google Dataproc cluster and submit a job to it.

I would like to be able to customize the cluster (number of workers) and the job (arguments passed to it) through the `dag_run.conf` parameter.

### Cluster creation

For the cluster creation, I wrote a logic with something like:

```py
DataprocCreateClusterOperator(...
        cluster_config = {...
             num_workers = "{% if 'cluster' is in dag_run.conf and 'secondary_worker_config' is in dag_run.conf['cluster'] and 'num_instances' is in dag_run.conf['cluster']['secondary_worker_config'] %}{{ dag_run.conf['cluster']['secondary_worker_config']['num_instances'] }}{% else %}16{% endif %}"
        }
)
```

That is to say, if `cluster.secondary_worker_config.num_instances` is available in `dag_run.conf`, use it, else fallback on default value `16`.

However, when rendered, this is expanded as a Python string, like `"16"`, leading to failure because the `num_workers` parameter must be an `int` or a `long`.

I cannot parse it to `int` during operator declaration:

```
num_workers = int("{% ... %}")
```

because this will try to interpret the whole jinja script as an integer (and not the resulting value).

Using the  `| int` jinja filter neither solve the problem.

### Job submission

I have a similar problem for job submission.
Operator expect a `job` dict argument, with field `spark.args` to provide arguments to the spark job. This field must be an iterable, and is expected to be a list of strings, e.g: `["--arg=foo", "bar"]`.

I want to be able to add some arguments by providing them through `dag_run.conf`:

```json
{
    args = ["--new_arg=baz", "bar2"]
}
```

But adding these arguments to the initial list doesn't seem to be possible. You either get a single argument for all additional args: `["--arg=foo", "bar", "--new_arg=baz bar2"]`, or a single string with all arguments.

In any case, the resulting job submission is not working as expected...

---

Is there an existing way to workaround this problem?

If not, is there a way to add a "casting step" after "template rendering" one, either in the provider operators or directly in the `BaseOperator` abstract class?

---

## Edit

I think that the solution proposed by [Josh Fell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638299/4373898) is the way to go. However, for those that don't want to upgrade Airflow, I tried to implement the solution proposed by Jarek.

```py
import unittest
import datetime
from typing import Any

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator, TaskInstance


# Define an operator which check its argument type at runtime (during "execute")
class TypedOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, int_param: int, **kwargs):
        super(TypedOperator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.int_param = int_param

    def execute(self, context: Any):
        assert(type(self.int_param) is int)


# Extend the "typed" operator with an operator handling templating
class TemplatedOperator(TypedOperator):
    template_fields = ['templated_param']

    def __init__(self,
                 templated_param: str = "{% if 'value' is in dag_run.conf %}{{ dag_run.conf['value'] }}{% else %}16{% endif %}",
                 **kwargs):
        super(TemplatedOperator, self).__init__(int_param=int(templated_param), **kwargs)


# Run a test, instantiating a task and executing it
class JinjaTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_templating(self):
        print("Start test")
        dag = DAG("jinja_test_dag", default_args=dict(
            start_date=datetime.date.today().isoformat()
        ))
        print("Task intanciation (regularly done by scheduler)")
        task = TemplatedOperator(task_id="my_task", dag=dag)
        print("Done")

        print("Task execution (only done when DAG triggered)")
        context = TaskInstance(task=task, execution_date=datetime.datetime.now()).get_template_context()
        task.execute(context)
        print("Done")

        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Which give the output:

```
Start test

Task intanciation (regularly done by scheduler)

Ran 1 test in 0.006s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexis/AdYouLike/Repositories/data-airflow-dags/tests/data_airflow_dags/utils/tasks/test_jinja.py", line 38, in test_templating
    task = TemplatedOperator(task_id="my_task", dag=dag)
  File "/home/alexis/AdYouLike/Repositories/data-airflow-dags/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 89, in __call__
    obj: BaseOperator = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alexis/AdYouLike/Repositories/data-airflow-dags/tests/data_airflow_dags/utils/tasks/test_jinja.py", line 26, in __init__
    super(TemplatedOperator, self).__init__(int_param=int(templated_param), **kwargs)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "{% if 'value' is in dag_run.conf %}{{ dag_run.conf['value'] }}{% else %}16{% endif %}"
```

As you can see, this fails at the task instanciation step, because in the `TemplatedOperator.__init__` we try to cast to int the JINJA template (and not the rendered value).
Maybe I missed a point in this solution, but it seems to be unusable as is.

Comment: What Airflow version are you using?

Comment: @JoshFell I use v2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately all Jinja templates are rendered as strings so the solution proposed by @JarekPotiuk is your best bet.

However, for anyone using Airflow 2.1+ or if you'd like to upgrade, there is a new parameter that can be set at the DAG level: `render_template_as_native_obj`

When enabling this parameter, the output from Jinja templating will be returned as native Python types (e.g. list, tuple, int, etc.).  Learn more here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects

Answer (score 2):

THe easiest way is to define your custom operator deriving from `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` . It's super easy and you can even do it within the dag file:

Conceptually something like that:

```
class MyDataprocCreateClusterOperator(DataprocCreateClusterOperator):
   template_fields = DataprocCreateClusterOperator.template_fields + ['my_param']
   def __init__(my_param='{{ ... }}', .....):
      super(int_param=int(my_param), ....)
```

Comment: Can you extend a little bit the example? Where does the variable `param` come from? If it is `my_param`, then `int_param=int(my_param)` will surely fail, as you try to cast to int a full jinja script (`{{ ... }}`) and not the rendered value. This was one of my idea, but I didn't found where to put my code, having access to rendered value, and casting it before the call to `super.execute`.

Comment: corrected a typo - should be int(my_param)  - and the value comes from JINJA template (so my_param will be your string parameter and then it can be cast to int in super()

Comment: However the feature from 2.1 which Josh mentioned seems to be much better approach